# How do you pass an argument to a composer script from the command line?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to run a custom composer script via cli like so:

`composer custom_script_cli --custom_argument`

What happens is composer thinks i'm asking composer if i want to pass that argument to composer instead of the custom script.

Is there a way to do this without forcefully adding it to the custom script itself?

Only thing I found relevant to this topic was a [git issue from 2013](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2135) which at that time says it's not possible. Not sure if this is still the case 4 years later.

Comment: `composer custom_script_cli -- --custom_argument` perhaps? Note the double dashes (`--`) in their to separate arguments.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Any kind of arguments may be passed to custom-composer-scripts simply
by appending them on the command-line as usual but after a `--`
(i.e. the special argument separation operator, which is not passed to the scripts itself).

However, you do not need to use the `--` argument separation operator
when NONE of the arguments begin with any hyphens
(i.e. what are generally called command-line options, like `-o` or `--option`)
else `composer` would treat them as an option to `composer` itself, and not to the script.

If the custom script definition runs multiple commands then the arguments passed will appended to every command. Also you can't use shell programming conventions like `$2` to refer to individual arguments.

If the custom script is handled by a callback, it is the script's responsibility to parse options from arguments. From the callback's perspective things like `-c` and `--option=B` are arguments.

### Example

Given a `composer.json` with the following contents:

```
{
    "autoload": { "psr-4": { "MyVendor\\": "./" } },
    "scripts": {
        "pass-args-to-callback": [
            "MyVendor\\MyClass::myCallback"
        ],
        "pass-args-to-commands": [
            "echo one",
            "echo two",
            "@other-command"
        ],
        "other-command": [
            "echo three"
        ]
    }
}
```

And given a file `MyClass.php` with the following contents:

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor;

use Composer\Script\Event;
use Composer\Installer\PackageEvent;

class MyClass {
    public static function myCallback(Event $event) {
        var_dump($event->getArguments());
    }
}
```

#### Step 0: Dump Autoloader to recognize MyClass

```
$ composer dump-autoload
Generating autoload files
```

#### Test 1: Show what happens without the argument separation operator

```
$ composer pass-args-to-callback A --option=B -C


  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
  The "--option" option does not exist.


pass-args-to-callback [--dev] [--no-dev] [--] [<args>]...
```

#### Test 2: Show how arguments and options appear in the callback

```
$ composer pass-args-to-callback -- A --option=B -C
> MyVendor\MyClass::myCallback
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "--option=B"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "-C"
}
```

#### Test 3: Show how arguments and options are appended to commands

```
$ composer pass-args-to-commands -- A --option=B -C
> echo one 'A' '--option=B' '-C'
one A --option=B -C
> echo two 'A' '--option=B' '-C'
two A --option=B -C
> echo three 'A' '--option=B' '-C'
three A --option=B -C
```

Reference: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md

Answer (score 10):

You may add the double dashes `--` to the end of your script entry(s).

This way you can pass additional arguments/options to the underlying script.

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "test": "phpunit",
        "test-single": "phpunit --"
    }
}
```

To run the `test-single` script with a custom phpunit filter:

```
composer test-single --filter test_function
```

Comment: This seems to not work. I got `The "--filter" option does not exist.` when running the above example.

Answer (score -2):

You may pass arguments just at the end so:

```
composer custom_script_cli [--dev] [--no-dev] [--] [<args>]...
```

Which means something like this

```
composer custom_script_cli argument1 argument2
```

And then you may get it in your script like this:

```
public static function commandcode(Event $event) {
   $event->getArguments(); ...
}
```

The thing that you refer to is called an option.