# Good practice for composer scripts arguments

Tags: php, command-line, composer-php

I just created a simple script which is supposed to be called with composer.
So, I passed some arguments to my command line line

```
composer deploySources -- $SSH_HOST $SSH_USER $SSH_PASSWORD
```

But, by doing this way, I can only pass arguments in a specific order and I find it a bit messy.
And I find the command line not really explicit aswell.

So I decided to do it this way:

```
composer deploySources -- server=$SSH_HOST login=$SSH_USER password=$SSH_PASSWORD directory=$SOURCE_PATH
```

And then, create a small tool to explode all my arguments and returns me an associative array like :

```
["server" => "foo", "login" => "bar" ...]
```

It's ok, the job is done this way but now, I'm asking myself.

Is it the good way to do, or am I missing something in the composer documentation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you pass an argument to a composer script from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44910354/how-do-you-pass-an-argument-to-a-composer-script-from-the-command-line)

Comment: So shellwise, the propose way would be: `composer deploySources -- --server=$SSH_HOST --login=$SSH_USER --password=$SSH_PASSWORD`