# How to pass arguments to custom composer script

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, phpunit

In my Laravel project, I want to run phpunit for a single file, like this one:

```
$ composer run-script test tests/Unit/Services/OrderServiceTest.php
```

Here is my composer setup:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": [
        "@testenv",
        "@phpunit"
    ],
    "testenv": [
        "php artisan config:cache --env=testing",
        "php artisan config:clear"
    ],
    "phpunit": [
        "php ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --"
    ]
}
```

However, I'm running into this error:

> www@287dd7480e22:/var/www$ composer run-script test tests/Unit/Services/OrderServiceTest.php
>
> php artisan config:cache --env=testing 'tests/Unit/Services/OrderServiceTest.php'
>
> Too many arguments, expected arguments "command".

Notice:

- I've seen this post: [How do you pass an argument to a composer script from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44910354/how-do-you-pass-an-argument-to-a-composer-script-from-the-command-line). But either the solution (adding `--` at the end of custom composer script) does not work for my case or I do not understand it properly.
- If I do not pass an argument, the script runs without a problem. (i.e. run phpunit for all test files)

Comment: Probably because your argument is passed to both your commands, the first one being the `artisan` command that doesn't accept such argument as the error mentions. What you could do instead is split your commands into two: `composer test-env && composer phpunit tests/Unit/Services/OrderServiceTest.php` (or `(composer test-env) -and (composer phpunit tests/Unit/Services/OrderServiceTest.php)` under Windows). There might be a way to pass your arguments to only the last command though, but I'm not aware of it.

Comment: @Jeto I know the exact reason, and I want to solve it in more elegant way: *pass your arguments to only the last command* - yep

Comment: Another way would be to have your `test` script be a single entry with `php artisan config:cache --env=testing && php artisan config:clear && @phpunit` (because, sadly, `@testenv && @phpunit` wouldn't work), which should do exactly what you want but that's duplicating the `@testenv` command lines in the composer.json file which is not ideal. Anyway, I'm not seeing any perfect solution here, but maybe someone else knows of one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to [this comment in composer repository](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/9163#issuecomment-688380654):

> There is no way to pass arguments only to one of the sub-scripts if you do a script group and call multiple things..

Answer (score 3):

There is a trick that allows you to ignore an argument for a sub-script:

```json
"scripts": {
    "testenv": [
        "php artisan config:cache --env=testing || exit $?",
        ...
    ],
    ...
}
```

What happens here is that your argument (let's say `OrderServiceTest.php`) is appended to the whole command line, but the shell command `exit` ignores any further arguments after the exit code. And for the exit code we set `$?` which is the exit code of the last running command in order to not change the overall outcome.